# Problem with max() in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have alphanumeric values like. XYZ1,XYZ2......XYZ11, XYZ12 and so on, now I want to select only the Max numeric value, i.e. 12 here.
I tried-

```
 select max(REPLACE(ID,'XYZ','')) from myTable;
```

but this is returning 9. why?

Comment: Do you also expect `'XYZ9' < 'XYZ12'`?

Comment: It's my bad, I should have noticed it's a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try converting to INT before `max`

```
select max(cast(REPLACE(ID,'XYZ','') as int)) from myTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's still treating your value as a string instead of a number. Try:

```
select max(CAST(REPLACE(ID,'XYZ','') AS INT) from myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're still comparing strings. The fact that they contain only numeric digits doesn't mean that they're not strings. You need to convert them:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(id, 'XYZ', '') AS INT)) FROM My_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is

```
select max(REPLACE(ID,'XYZ','')*1) from myTable
```